# Django single model multiple form

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a single table say **'push_message'** to send push messages to multiple device type **i.e STB,Andriod, Feature phone**. I create a single model for this. But different fields are mandatory for different device type.
Is there any way I may use same model with different form(Suppose STB & Android)

```
class PushNotification(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sched_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    alert_ty = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=Options.alert_type())
    title = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    device_ty = models.CharField(max_length=24, choices=Options.get_devices())
```

Based on device type few fields are may mandatory. So I want to make form based on device chosen by user.

Please provide your input how may I achieve this in Django 2.1.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Model is strictly representing a database in django. So having some fields "optionally" required wont work. I suggest creating them as "not required" in the db and then define them as required **(required = True)** in form:

```
class SomeCustomForm(DefaultForm):
    form_field = forms.BooleanField( label='Very important field'),
                                     required=True,
                                     error_messages={'required':'Can`t proceed without this'})
```

If you want a dropdown with a list of devices and validate the form depending on it you might want to use custom **clean()** as per documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/):

> The form subclass’s clean() method can perform validation that requires access to multiple form fields. This is where you might put in checks such as “if field A is supplied, field B must contain a valid email address”. This method can return a completely different dictionary if it wishes, which will be used as the cleaned_data.

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    cc_myself = cleaned_data.get("cc_myself")
    subject = cleaned_data.get("subject")

    if cc_myself and subject:
        # Only do something if both fields are valid so far.
        if "help" not in subject:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "Did not send for 'help' in the subject despite "
                "CC'ing yourself."
            )
```

Comment: Thanks for providing ur input. Solution will not works for me. Suppose I have some docs in different format(pdf, word, odt), for different format it is not advisable to create separate table-model. I guess question is now more clear.

Comment: Why is it not advisable to create more tables? Most received wisdom about relational databases suggests otherwise. Although a table of documents can cope perfectly well with different file types and recipient-device specification field(s).

Comment: @nigel222 Based on only one attribute, it is not advisable to create new table. Here based on device type we need to set attribute value. is it only solution to create separate tables?(I think in multiple document type i.e. word, pdf, excel etc.) Need to create for content document type, as I per my understanding.

Comment: @dinu0101, you can create not required fields in db and call **clean()** method to check data integrity during form submission as i stated before - then you can fit everything in one table

Comment: @Serhii, would u share link or sample with me which work as you said. I am newbie to Python & Django. Thank you for your guide & support.

Comment: @dinu0101 sorry, quite overwhelmed at work:) But the general idea is - in your model define fields like you already did (without `required = True`) and then in clean() method of the form - 1. Call `cleaned_data = super().clean()` to get default validation. And make necessary check comparing data from that structure (like:`if device_type == Android and android_required_field == None: 
rais`)

Comment: all fields will be in the cleaned_data so you can check whatever you want with them